# Why should I load the images in same size to texture for animation?

Tags: sprite-kit

In iOS Sprite Kit, why should I load the images, in same size, to texture for animation? If the images size are various, I can not make the animation run. What is the theory? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you init a SKSpriteNode, its size is set unless you change it later with code. Changing the sprite's texture to another image with a different size will cause the image to potentially become distorted as SK will scale the texture to the node's size. For example, if the node is created with a 100x100 texture and then gets a 50x100 texture, the image will be stretched sideways to make it 100x100.

When creating images for animation sequences always make sure you have the same size for each one. Use alpha to fill the spaces on the edges.